# Inconsistency of Reinhardt cardinals in ZF+DC

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

As I'm just a layperson I don't understand the technicalities involved, but does the paper *New Large Cardinal Axioms and the Ultimate-L Program*, by Rupert McCallum (arXiv:[1812.03837](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.03837)) prove the inconsistency of a Reinhardt cardinal? If so can someone explain how given the results of the paper one proves Reinhardt cardinals to be inconsistent in ZF+DC?

Comment: I have not read McCallum's paper, but he is well-known that his attempts of [the proof of P≠NP](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.10080), and the [failed proof of the non-existence of a super Reinhardt cardinal.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.09678) Thus we should be careful of his result.

Comment: On Facebook Rupert has admitted that errors have been pointed out.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo is this a public post? If so, do you have a link?

Comment: Yes, but I would prefer if he shows up and clarifies. I'll post a link in a few days otherwise.

Comment: @David https://www.facebook.com/rupert.mccallum/posts/10157606476682539

Comment: A colleague (Gabriel Goldberg) was corresponding with me about Section 5 of the paper and raised a difficulty which I am thinking through at present. The paper is under review by Bulletin of Symbolic Logic and when I have the first peer-reviewer's report from that then I will make all the corrections that I feel need to be made. I feel a bit awkward about making a public comment about Section 5 right at this moment, and I do think it is the most vulnerable section.

Comment: But I'm thinking maybe what is up there at the moment is still enough, with a few tweaks, to show inconsistency of ZF+DC+j:V_{\lambda+3} \rightarrow V_{\lambda+3}, or possibly even I can get rid of DC, and I don't mind talking it through with people who want to talk it through. My confidence was shaken a little bit by some remarks that Gabriel Goldberg made in private correspondence, basically the issue is the bit where I say "the function mapping n to the chosen member of the equivalence class of  X is eventually constant".

Comment: I think I agree with Gabriel Goldberg that that point definitely needs to be clarified, and as I say I don't mind trying to talk about the issues here with whoever wants to discuss it. It is fair to say that Section 5 should be clarified further. And I would be happy to get started on that straightaway if only I had a peer-reviewer's report in my hands. Perhaps it is best if people just wait for the peer-reviewer to do his/her good work and I promise I shall be fully forthcoming about whether the argument is beyond repair.

Comment: To the OP: When you say "explain", is there a bit of Section 5 you want me to expand on a bit more?

Comment: @Rupert of course the issue is my ignorance of the topic rather than a flaw in the paper, but I just wasn't sure what was meant by "most of the choiceless hierarchy" - it might be nice for layperson readers like me to specifically say "most of the choiceless hierarchy including Reinhardt cardinals". But it's of course not essential as the target audience of the paper would be aware of this point.

Comment: Oh, yeah, actually that part of Section 5 maybe does need to be modified a bit, but if you take a look at "Large Cardinals Beyond Choice", I think it's by Hugh Woodin, Peter Koellner, and Joan Bagaria, that will describe "the choiceless hierarchy". Like you have Reinhardt cardinal, super-Reinhardt cardinal, Berkeley cardinal, and limit club Berkeley cardinal, roughly speaking. And I recently reviewed (not peer-reviewed, just wrote a review of) one paper saying there's a lot of nice structure theory at the level of a Berkeley cardinal.

Comment: As everyone has been pointing out, it's highly ambitious for me to say I might have shown Reinhardt cardinals are inconsistent, it's under peer review at present, the version that is up there definitely needs a re-write, and it's important not to get too excited.

Comment: @Rupert I'm guessing your paper has nothing to do with Woodin's enormous cardinal (http://logic.harvard.edu/EFI_Woodin_talk.pdf)

Comment: Ah yes, correct. I think in that talk for him an "enormous cardinal" is a cardinal $\kappa$ such that there exist ordinals $\lambda, \gamma$ such that $\kappa<\lambda<\gamma$ and $V_{\kappa} \prec V_{\lambda} \prec V_{\gamma}$ and there is an elementary embedding $j:V_{\lambda+1} \rightarrow V_{\lambda+1}$ with critical point $\kappa$ (if I recall correctly).

Comment: My $\alpha$-enormous cardinals are different to that, similar but slightly higher amount of consistency strength. Apologies for doubling up on the use of the word "enormous" but I admit I am not very creative about inventing new words for new large-cardinal properties. For "tremendous" a friend suggested I have a look at a thesaurus for synonyms for "enormous".

Comment: Colossal cardinal? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before explaining the results, there are some facts that should be noted:

1. Arxiv papers are not peer-certified scientific papers. It is very possible, and in fact very common, for false theorems to appear on Arxiv. They are endless papers detailing proofs of the inconsistency of $ZFC$ for instance.
2. Rupert McCallum has published, on arxiv, a number of papers containing theorems whose proofs were later discovered to be false, such as his proof of the inconsistency of super Reinhardt cardinals.
3. The main results contained in the paper are almost certainly **false**. This is because the problems related to $V=\text{Ultimate-}L$ are some of the most important problems related to set theory. If they were solved, every set theorist would be discussing the solution. The results would certainly not be relegated to a relatively unknown paper on arxiv.

Now, as to your main question. The paper **claims** to prove the inconsistency of the existence of a cardinal $\lambda$ and some non-trivial elementary embedding $j: V_{\lambda+3}\prec V_{\lambda+3}$ with $ZF+DC$. If this is true, then this also means the Reinhardt cardinals are inconsistent.

This is because, if $j: V\prec V$ is a non-trivial elementary embedding with critical point $\kappa$,  and $\lambda=\text{sup}\{\kappa,j(\kappa),j^2(\kappa)...\}$, then $j(\lambda)=\lambda$. Therefore, $j\restriction V_{\lambda+3}: V_{\lambda+3}\prec V_{\lambda+3}$ is a non-trivial elementary embedding with critical point $\kappa$.

Comment: Not to take away from the work of Hugh Woodin, but is V=Ultimate L *"by far, the most important problems related to set theory being discussed right now."* I don't think so, and I don't think we should be making these kind of statements either. They shine a light on a specific point in set theory and obscure the rest.

Comment: I meant it because, while there are many other open <b>fields</b>, this consists of basically a single question. I as I understand, it is similar to Fermat's Last Theorem. There are plenty of other fields, however it is the only singular <b>question</b> that is being discussed with such emphasis. I have removed the line, however.

Comment: I'm totally happy to agree with you that they are ambitious claims and they should be regarded as doubtful until such time as the first peer-reviewer's report has been arrived, and if they are untenable I shall publicly retract them. I haven't been made aware of why the claims of Section 6 can't work.

Comment: "Rupert McCallum has published on Arxiv a number of theorems later discovered to be false". 

There's one about Kac-Moody groups over finite fields which has mistakes in it, although you don't know the result is false, I'm still working on it, and with attempted proof of inconsistency of super-Reinhardt you don't know that it's false. I did agree the attempted argument at the time didn't establish the conclusion. I think your statement is not exactly demonstrably true.

Comment: I agree that you are justified in believing that the claims are not very likely to be true, if you haven't read the paper. I've been waiting on a peer reviewer's report for 19 months.

Comment: I should clarify: The proofs of those theorems were false. Since all of the assertions have consistency higher than those of $ZFC$, it is impossible to prove conclusively that they are false

Comment: I have deleted a couple of comments here (and edited my more detailed answer posted below) since a good friend said I should not come across as "passive-agressively defensive". Anyway, the basic main message of your post is quite right, it is entirely reasonable to treat these results with skepticism.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Tidying this up to make it appear less "passive-aggressively" defensive on the good advice of a friend...

[paragraph deleted]

I should just clarify, I said that I've been waiting on a peer-reviewer's report for 19 months and it sounds like I'm complaining, but I'm not, these are times of COVID, and any time an expert volunteers to check your work the correct answer is always "Thank you, I really appreciate what you're doing". In addition, regarding P versus NP, Henry Towsner was most kind to volunteer his time and effort to give feedback on an earlier version, and I think he might have been a bit frustrated about perceived lack of clarity in the write-up, so I'm sorry about that, however I've addressed the concerns he raised, the current version is up there on Arxiv, I have not been made aware of why it is wrong, Annals of Mathematics have said "the editors will have a look and get back to you" but no more than that. And now, back to Ultimate-$L$ and inconsistency of Reinhardt.

Okay. I agree the version of the Ultimate-$L$ paper up there right now needs a bit of a re-write. Here's how the whole thing works. I'm going to open with a discussion of how I came up with the $\alpha$-tremendous and $\alpha$-enormous cardinals and why I think they're consistent.

First of all, check out this one which is recently accepted for publication.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.8058

You'll find me explaining there in some detail why I think belief in large cardinals up to a supercompact cardinal is justified (roughly speaking). It's a bit of a delicate matter whether I want to say that a prediction of consistency of a supercompact is epistemically warranted, I'll write a bit about that some other time. But, to the extent that we can speak of "intrinsic justifications" in set theory in the sense defined in that paper, yeah I am roughly saying I think a supercompact cardinal should be seen as intrinsically justified. I'm a little bit more nuanced in exactly how I state the three main theses of the paper. I also cite Victoria Marshall, I think if you take the same line of thought a bit further with reference to Victoria Marshall then it's pretty fair to say that $n$-huge cardinals are justified. But Victoria Marshall went all the way up to the point of inconsistency with the axiom of choice. So what went wrong.

So let's talk about what Victoria Marshall does when she motivates $n$-huge cardinals. She has a fixed sequence of length $n$ of "sub-universes" of the Universe $V$, right, and the idea is that you start with a formula $\phi$ and a parameter from your universe $V$ and you reflect downwards, going through your sequence of sub-universes, roughly speaking, and there's an elementary embedding which guides how your parameter gets reflected downward, and you're saying reflection like that always works, and that's equivalent to the ordinal height of your smallest sub-universe being an $n$-huge cardinal, or something. I'm being very vague here but it's all presented in detail in Victoria Marshall's "Higher Order Reflection Principles" which you can find on JSTOR, and I will be more precise when we get up to my own arguments, I explaining here how to motivate the $\alpha$-tremendous and $\alpha$-enormous cardinals.

So you see, when Victoria Marshall goes all the way up to $j:V_{\lambda+2} \rightarrow V_{\lambda+2}$, here's the problem. I'll be showing you shortly how you motivate the $\alpha$-tremendous cardinals assuming that Victoria Marshall's motivation of $n$-hugeness is okay, and then those ones rank-reflect I3 as shown in Section 2, yes I do believe the version of Section 2 that is currently up there is okay, let me know if anyone can see issues there. So if $\alpha$-tremendous cardinals are okay then I3 cardinals are okay. You're all right with $j:V_{\lambda+1} \rightarrow V_{\lambda+1}$ as well, because if you've got an I3 embedding which you use to reflect parameters in $V_{\lambda}$ then you're okay with saying it can reflect parameters in $V_{\lambda+1}$ as well because there's only one possible choice for how your parameter can be reflected. But when you go to $V_{\lambda+2}$ that's no longer the case, and that's why that much reflection is dodgy. You understand, at this point I am simply talking about vague philosophical arguments which I will write up properly in some future paper. Now we're up to how I came up with the $\alpha$-tremendous and $\alpha$-enormous cardinals and why I think they're well-motivated.

So for $\alpha$-tremendous you're assuming $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal greater than zero, and you've got a sequence of cardinals of length $\alpha$ less than your cardinal $\kappa$, and for any finite subsequence you can do reflection going down that sequence similar to what Victoria Marshall does. That's roughly the idea. The definition that's up there is the correct definition, and the arguments of Section 2 showing that you get something between I3 and I2 consistency-strength-wise are correct. Okay, let's go to $\alpha$-enormous.

In the definition that's up there, Definition 1.3, after I say "member of the $\kappa$th iterated HOD of $V_{\kappa}$", after that insert "and $k(S) \subseteq S$". Apart from that, definition that's up there is correct. I'm sure you don't want to hear any more philosophical waffle about why you should believe it's consistent, let's get up to some actual maths. If you can show it's inconsistent, you've killed it. I will defend Section 2 if anyone can poke holes in it, I think the version up there is fine, and let us totally ignore Section 3 and Section 4. My task is to expound on Section 5 and Section 6, and I'll do Section 6 first.

"It will follow from the results of this section together with known results
about the Ultimate-L Conjecture that Ultimate-L so defined does not
in fact depend on the choice of the sequence." Scratch that sentence, it might be dodgy. We'll do without it. We'll say this is a possibly non-unique Ultimate-$L$, which can be chosen to be $\Sigma_2$-definable without parameters if you want it to be.

"The necessary elementary embedding within the model can be constructed using arguments of Section 3." That was written when we had a different definition of $\alpha$-enormous. Now with the current definition of $\alpha$-enormous, don't even need to go back to Section 3, you've got the elementary embeddings you need in the inner model, it's fine.

"any supercompact cardinal is necessary hyper-enormous, and all necessary elementary embeddings for witnessing this do descend to the model Ultimate-$L$". And you've also got to note that all of the elementary embeddings you need for Magidor's characterisation of supercompactness would be available down there too.

"Well-known generic absoluteness results". What I'm talking about here is Theorem 14 of this one. It's in Section 3, on page 21.

http://logic.harvard.edu/koellner/QAU_reprint.pdf

Okay then. That argument which is up there on Arxiv, with all those modifications and clarifications. So yeah, what's wrong with it? I am happy to discuss. I guess if it falls down it will be the bit where I say I can find a universally Baire set which does what I want.

And proof of Theorem 5.5. Okay I just re-read it. Well, [un-named expert] said it's a probem that $e_{X,n}$ depends on $n$, or at least that's how I understood his point. What he said was "yes, you can do inverse limit reflection but it's not uniform" (roughly). Ah okay, got it, the elementary embeddings $e_{X,n}$ would have to fit together in the right way wouldn't they. No, I don't think I need that. It's all about the way my choice sets $C_{\alpha}$ fit together, I can get from one to the other using some member of a fixed family of elementary embeddings. That's really all I need. That's enough for saying "the function mapping $n$ to the chosen member of the equivalence class of $X$ is in fact eventually constant". But [un-named expert] thought there was a problem. I thought I saw why he thought there was a problem and now I don't see it, I think it's fine. I will defend the proof of Theorem 5.5 on request.

EDIT: See, here's the thing. Your parameter X is made up of $\omega$ many pieces from $V_{\kappa_0}$, $V_{\kappa_1} \setminus V_{\kappa_0}$, $V_{\kappa_2} \setminus V_{\kappa_1}$, $\ldots$, and yeah if you reflect those down with the different embeddings $e_{X,n}$, then sure a different embedding will give you a different reflected piece of your parameter. But you'll eventually be up the point where you're in the "tail" which all your different choice functions are going to leave unchanged. It's like, when I'm past a certain point, I reflect it down, use my choice function, then lift it back up again, and when you're past a certain point there's a certain "tail" of your countable set of ordinals which the choice function isn't going to touch. When $n$ is sufficiently big then $e_{X,n}$ is not going to modify the bit that's not in the tail, and the tail itself doesn't get changed by the choice function, so you're just reflecting down and lifting back up again. That's the trick. That's why I can say it's eventually constant. This is the bit that [un-named expert] convinced me I ought to clarify.

Comment: I am not an expert in the Ultimate-$L$ conjecture, however I have attempted to read through the paper, and there are several places where it states that construction can be done, and provides evidence that the construction can be done, but never outright does the construction. Perhaps I am simply inexperienced, but could it be that there are "traps" hiding in these small holes?

Comment: It could be. Like, I don't have any problem at all with saying that the current version needs a re-write, and I'll do a proper re-write when I've got the first peer-reviewer's report, so for now it should be taken to be "work in progress". I have no problem with that at all.

Comment: Looking at the definition of $\alpha$ tremendous cardinals, would it be accurate to say that $\kappa$ is $\alpha$-tremendous if there is some sequence $\langle\kappa_\beta|\beta\lt\alpha\rangle$ with $V_{\kappa_\beta}\prec V_\kappa$, such that for any sequence $\langle\beta_i|i\lt\omega\rangle\subseteq\alpha$, if $\lambda=\text{sup}\kappa_{\beta_i}$, there is some $j: V_\lambda\prec V_\lambda$ with critical sequence $\langle\kappa_{\beta_i}|i\lt\omega\rangle$?

Comment: You have a family of elementary embeddings, one for each finite subsequence of your sequence of length $\alpha$, so saying you can get I3 elementary embeddings out of that is not quite obvious to me right now. What I try to do is show that each one of these things rank-reflects a stationary set of I3 cardinals.

Comment: Bear with me here. I'm an amateur when it comes to this. I'm asking is it true, that this is an equivalent definition.

Comment: I believe what you describe is a little bit stronger than what I've got, but still consistent relative to I1. I claim to have shown that my tremendous cardinals are consistent relative to I2.

Comment: I believe that they are equivalent. Let $j_n: V_{\kappa_{\beta_n}}\prec V_{\kappa_{\beta_{n+1}}}$, and then define $j: V_\lambda\prec V_\lambda$ by taking any $x\in V_\lambda$, let $n$ be the least ordinal $x\in V_{\beta_n}$, and let $j(x)=j_n(x)$. Then $V_\lambda\vDash\phi(x)\leftrightarrow V_{\kappa_{\beta_n}}\vDash\phi(x)\leftrightarrow V_{\kappa_{\beta_{n+1}}}\vDash\phi(j(x))\leftrightarrow V_\lambda\vDash\phi(j(x))$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116405/discussion-between-rupert-and-master).

Comment: I have sent this message before, but I am afraid you might not have seen the notification, so I will repost it here: I believe there is a flaw in the proof of Theorem 6.4. You assume that for every $\alpha\gt 0$, there is an $\alpha$-enormous cardinal. You state that any supercompact cardinals is necessarily hyper-enormous, assuming the previous large cardinal hypothesis. However, let $\kappa$ be the least supercompact cardinal, and let $\langle\kappa_\beta|\beta\lt\kappa\rangle$ witness that $\kappa$ is hyper-enormous [cont.]

Comment: Then, as $\kappa_0$ is the critical point of a rank-into-rank embedding, $V_{\kappa_0}$ believes there is a proper class of supercompact cardinals, and since $V_{\kappa_0}\prec V_\kappa$, we have that there is a proper class of supercompact cardinals in $V_\kappa$. In particular, there is some $\lambda\lt\kappa$ which is supercompact in $V_\kappa$. However, since $\kappa$ is supercompact, $\lambda$ must be actually supercompact in $V$. But this contradicts the smallness of $\kappa$.

Comment: Thanks. That does seem like a good objection.

Comment: You've shown that my attempt to justify the claim that the model is a weak extender model for supercompactness of $\delta$ is not okay as it stands, the question is can I rescue that claim some other way. I will think about it. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Possibly I may be able to justify a slightly different claim with regard to any supercompact cardinal $\delta$, not fully hyper-enormous but some slightly weaker property which is still good enough for what I want. But anyway. Clearly this requires thought. Thanks a lot for your feedback.

Comment: I am glad to be able to have helped in any way. I think it may be possible to construct Ultimate-$L$ locally, inside $V_\Omega$ when $\Omega$ is hyper-enormous, and it will be a weak-extender model. If you are interested, I can write up my construction.

Comment: That is kind of you, maybe it is all right with you if we just wait until the editor responds to the email I sent him just now explaining that you had pointed out a mistake, and maybe I can have just a bit of a go at trying to rescue it myself, and then yes we should discuss this further. Perhaps we can communicate by email about it.